# How to add a New Drive to Netbackup 6 on a Linux host?

Tags: linux, netbackup

My tape drive needed to be replaced.  I am using netbackup 6 and 2.6.9 Linux.  When I try to re add the device I used /dev/nst0 as it is the nstX device.

/proc/scsi/scsi shows:
H

```
ost: scsi1 Channel: 00 Id: 05 Lun: 00
Vendor: HP Model: Ultrium 3-SCSI Rev: G63Z
Type: Sequential-Access ANSI SCSI revision: 03
```

However, when I go to drive Diagnostic in the GUI I get

```
Vendor Name: -
Model: -
Firmware: -
Drive path: MISSING_DRIVE:HU10548V5B
Drive Type: hcart 3
```

And when I run the Diagnostic the first Drive Information Test returns "Drive not DOWN, aborting test'

Anyone know what I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This thread](http://www.symantec.com/connect/forums/replace-tape-drive-0) has some good info on replacing drives... you'll need to delete the old drive & re-add the new drive.

From the last post in the thread:

---

To delete the old drive from NetBackup:

```
tpconfig -delete -drive <drvindex>
```

To delete old robot from NetBackup:

```
tpconfig -delete -robot <robot>
```

If this was the only tape drive you had on this system, go to /dev/rmt directory and remove everything. Assuming your drive is SCSI attached. If drive is Fiber connected and you are using zoning, then you need to update the zone at switch and/or host level.

After rebooting the server, you should be able to see devices created in /dev/rmt directory

run sgscan or scan command to check the new devices.

Now, you can add robot and drive either by using GUI or from the command line

Add new robot:

```
tpconfig -add -robot <robnum> -robtype <robtype> -robpath <devfile>
```

Restart NBU daemons

Add the new tape drive:

```
tpconfig -add -drive -type <drvtype> -path <drivepath> -asciiname <asciidrvname> -index <drvindex> -shared [yes|no] -drstatus UP|DOWN|DISABLED [-robot <robnum> -robtype <robtype> -robdrnum <robdrvnum>
```

Restart NBU daemons.

Update/recreate STU and you should be good to go

Comment: Good info, I had done similar steps but in the end just restarting netbackup didn't work.  The Following seems to have resolved it (Total shutdown and restart):

- Completely shutting down the tape library
- restarting the tape library, waiting for the system to finish its post
- Restarting the Netbackup Server Host